# Branching / merging strategy for TFS 2015 with Git repository for multi-team efforts?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, tfs-2015

We are planning to use TFS 2015 with Git repository and need ideas for branching and merging strategy? We have one team working on new enhancements and another team working on defects fixes (O&M). How do merge these efforts and keep things in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have described, although, some more information would be required, and also your question can be considered subjective and can result in opinion based answers, it would seem that the git flow branching model might be a good fit.

It handles the ability to have multiple streams of work through using the following branches:

- feature
- release
- hotfix

There is also a natural extension point in the form of support branches, which allow you to maintain older versions of your applications, as well as the current active development.

You can find more information about it [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: Thank you for the article, it's actually one of better ones.